# Terraform error - RDS Cluster FinalSnapshotIdentifier is required when a final snapshot is required

Tags: amazon-web-services, terraform, amazon-rds, terraform-provider-aws

I am new to Terraform. I am using Terraform to write AWS scripts. I am getting an error while performing **Terraform Destroy**. Terraform script is

```
resource "aws_rds_cluster" "aurora-cluster-ci" {
  cluster_identifier        = "aurora-cluster-ci"
  engine                    = "aurora-mysql"
  availability_zones        = ["us-east-1a", "us-east-1b", "us-east-1c"]
  database_name             = "${var.rds_dbname}"
  master_username           = "${var.rds_username}"
  master_password           = "${var.rds_password}"
  backup_retention_period   = 5
  engine_version            = "5.7.16"
  preferred_backup_window   = "07:00-09:00"
  apply_immediately         = true
  final_snapshot_identifier = "ci-aurora-cluster-backup"
  skip_final_snapshot       = true
}
```

> **Terraform Destroy** throws an error "aws_rds_cluster.aurora-cluster-ci: RDS Cluster
>   FinalSnapshotIdentifier is required when a final snapshot is required"

I have "final_snapshot_identifier" key in my script.

Comment: Can you show the exact error message?

Comment: https://github.com/hashicorp/terraform/issues/5417#issuecomment-223733146

Answer (score 33):

#### Solution:

I Encountered the same problem while trying to perform a `destroy` on an RDS instance (not under AWS Aurora) but the principles are the same.

Below are a few steps I took in order to solve this issue:

1. Change `skip_final_snapshot` to `true` and remove `final_snapshot_identifier` if exists 
    (see comments #1 and #2 below) .
2. Remove `backup_window` (Under AWS Aurora its probably called `preferred_backup_window`).
3. Change `backup_retention_period` to `0`.
4. Make sure that `apply_immediately` is set to `true` (see comment #3 below).
5. Run `terraform apply` and check the changes to affect (see a tip as comment #4 below).
6. Now you can run `terraform destroy` and no errors should appear (in my case I add `deletion_protection` set to `true` and add to remove it).

---

#### Comment #1 - Understanding the the purpose of the relevant fields

From [Terraform docs](https://www.terraform.io/docs/providers/aws/r/db_instance.html):

`skip_final_snapshot` - (Optional) Determines whether a final DB snapshot is created before the DB instance is deleted. If `true` is specified, no DBSnapshot is created. If `false` is specified, a DB snapshot is created before the DB instance is deleted, using the value from `final_snapshot_identifier`. Default is `false`.

`final_snapshot_identifier` - (Optional) The name of your final DB snapshot when this DB instance is deleted. Must be provided if `skip_final_snapshot` is set to `false`.

In the code specified in the question `skip_final_snapshot` was `true` and `final_snapshot_identifier` was still specified.

(*) Don't be confused with the `snapshot_identifier` field.

---

#### Comment #2 - What is causing this error?

For those who want to understand a little bit what is happening here, in the mentioned [open issue](https://github.com/terraform-providers/terraform-provider-aws/issues/2588) there is a nice thread where a contributor named @caiges gave a nice explanation there:

> For starters,
> `skip_final_snapshot` defaults to `False` which should also require
> `final_snapshot_identifier` to be set but it's not so what happens is
> the create/update is applied, state updated where `skip_final_snapshot`
> is `False` but `final_snapshot_identifier` is `null`. 
> This causes the
> destroy operation to fail it's verification stage.
>
> This can be fixed but I don't really have a great story for those who
> already have prexisting state. 
> One possibility would be that a delete
> operation ignores `skip_final_snapshot` if the identifier is null.
> Another might be to default `final_snapshot_identifier` to something
> random if `skip_final_snapshot` is set to or defaulted to False. 
>  I think
> for data safety reasons, ignoring `skip_final_snapshot` if
> `final_snapshot_identifier` is null is a bad idea and it'd be better to
> just randomize an identifier.

---

#### Comment #3 - Making sure our changes take immediate effect:

A note about `apply_immediately` from [Terraform's docs](https://www.terraform.io/docs/providers/aws/r/db_instance.html):

> Note: using apply_immediately can result in a brief downtime as the
> server reboots. See the AWS Docs on RDS Maintenance for more
> information.

---

#### Comment #4 (Bonus) - Saving ourselves some time:

When you run `terraform plan` make sure that the  `~` (update in-place sign) appears in the relevant fields under Terraform's execution plan - In the example below you can see that 2 changes will be applied:

```
~ resource "aws_db_instance" "postgresql" {
        address                               = ...
        allocated_storage                     = 100
        allow_major_version_upgrade           = false
        .
        .
      ~ apply_immediately                     = false -> true
        .
        .
      ~ backup_retention_period               = 7 -> 0
        .
        .
        tags                                  = ...
        username                              = ...
        vpc_security_group_ids  =  ...
    }
```

This might sound trivial, but in cases like this error, it can save a lot of debugging time when you try to understand why certain updates haven't took place.

Answer (score 11):

This is a known bug that is still open as of the current version of the Terraform provider for AWS:

https://github.com/terraform-providers/terraform-provider-aws/issues/2588

In a nutshell, it's ignoring the `skip_final_snapshot` parameter.

Answer (score 8):

In my case I had to manually edit the .tfstate file and set "skip_final_snapshot" to true. Then it worked.

Answer (score 4):

### If you're a Pulumi user seeing this error as Pulumi uses the Terraform provider:

`pulumi stack export > export.json`

Then change all instances of `skipFinalSnapshot` to `true`.

And import the changed file:

`pulumi stack import --file export.json`

Answer (score 3):

To delete RDS DB from  `terraform destroy`:-

1. first add `skip_final_snapshot  = "true" to your aws_provider`
2. do `terraform-apply`

Then you are able to destroy it.

3. `terraform destroy`

Answer (score 2):

Ran into the same issue, being a starter with RDS terraform resource you may miss skip_final_snapshot=true/false flag. By default this will be in false state and when you go for a terraform destroy it expects a snapshot name of the db causing the error.

*Name can be given with final_snapshot_identifier flag, if you want to create a final snap.

But now when you have created the RDS instance without knowing which obviously you wont.

just remove the state of that RDS instance

in my case:
1.) terraform state rm module.rds.aws_rds_instance_default
2.) Manually delete the RDS instance from the AWS console.
3.) reapply with terraform apply with skip_final_snapshot=true in aws_rds_instance resource.

or in case you want to  create instance snap when you destroy it.

set skip_final_snapshot=false, final_snapshot_identifier=name-of-snapshot.

Hope this helps !!Thanks

Answer (score 2):

If you want to update the db which needs the replacement of resource and you are getting an error of "RDS Cluster `FinalSnapshotIdentifier` is required when a final snapshot is required" then first comment out the parameters due to which replacement is required and add below parameter:

```
skip_final_snapshot = true
```

Then do "terraform apply".
Post that apply the updates which you want and run "terraform apply"
This solved my issue.

Answer (score 1):

I had the same issue but now I can destroy it after I changed the `skipFinalSnapshot` to `true` and `backup_retention_period` to `0` then I did terraform apply. Once these changes are applied and run the terraform destroy command. It will work.

Answer (score 0):

I was not able to delete an rds instance that I created through terraform scripts. Then I realized - It is not only enough to keep the skip_final_snapshot to true but also to do a terraform apply so that the changed value is taken into consideration. After that a terraform destroy does a proper deletion of the resources without the error 'Error: DB Instance FinalSnapshotIdentifier is required when a final snapshot is required'

Answer (score 0):

I ran into this problem because I was trying to make a change that forced replacement of the instance, while also trying to set `set_final_snapshot` to `true`.

Make sure that you run apply `set_final_snapshot = true` *before* applying the subsequent replacement-forcing change (two `apply`s in total).